# MethodNotAllowedHttpException error when doing validation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The following is my blade :

```
<form action="{{route('ans1.eval')}}" method="post">
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="evaluate" class="evaluate" value=10> 1   &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="evaluate" class="evaluate" value=15> 1.5 &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="evaluate" class="evaluate" value=20> 2   &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="evaluate" class="evaluate" value=25> 2.5 &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="evaluate" class="evaluate" value=30> 3   

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" align="right">Evaluate Answer</button>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
</form>
```

The following is my route :

```
Route::post('/evaluateans', [
    'uses' => 'AnswerController@postEvaluateAns',
    'as' => 'ans1.eval',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

The following is my validation :

```
public function postEvaluateAns(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
          'evaluate' => 'required'
    ]);
}
```

The following is the error when no evaluation is selected :

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the laravel docs on [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validation-quickstart)

> If the validation rules pass, your code will keep executing normally;
>   however, if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and the
>   proper error response will automatically be sent back to the user.  In
>   the case of a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response will be
>   generated.

When your validation fails it redirects **back** with a `GET` method (a redirection uses the `GET` method) but if you **show** the `form` from a `route` that is not a `GET` one it throws this error.

So you have to **show** the form with a `GET` route.

As alternative you can [manually create your validator](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#manually-creating-validators) so you can choose the redirect `GET` route in case of **failed** validation, e.g.:

```php
public function postEvaluateAns(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'evaluate' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('failed_validation_GET_route')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
    }
    return redirect()->route('success_GET_route')
                     ->with('status', 'Success!');
}
```